# How to get text from emenet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

```
<div class="container">

  <div>
    <p>Put your do to list</p>
  </div>

  <div class="toDo">
    <ul id="list">

    </ul>

  </div>


  <input type="text" id="userInputAdd" placeholder="add">
  <button id="add">Add</button>
  <input type="text" id="userInputRemove" placeholder="remove">
  <button id="remove">Remove</button>
</div>

$('#add').click(() => {
  $input = $('#userInputAdd').val()

  console.log($input)

  $('#list').append("<li>" + $input + "</li>")


})

$('#remove').click(function() {

  $removeINput = $('#remove').val()
  console.log($removeINput)

  $('#list').children().each((index, item) => {
    console.log(item)

    if ($removeINput === ** item ** ) {
      item.remove()
    }

  })
})
```

Comment: Please take your time and format the question so it's readable before posting another time

Comment: Please may you convert the code into a stacksnippet using the `<>` button?

Comment: Is this condition correct? ** if ($removeINput === ** item ** ) **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few mistakes in your code:

`$removeINput = $('#remove').val()` should be `$removeINput = $('#userInputRemove').val()` since `$('#remove')` is the button and not the input.

Also `if ($removeINput === ** item ** )` should be `if ($removeINput === $(item).text()  )`

**Demo**

```js
$('#add').click(() => {
  $input = $('#userInputAdd').val()

  console.log($input)

  $('#list').append("<li>" + $input + "</li>")


})

$('#remove').click(function() {

  $removeINput = $('#userInputRemove').val()
  console.log($removeINput)

  $('#list').children().each((index, item) => {
    console.log(item)

    if ($removeINput === $(item).text() ) {
      item.remove()
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div>
    <p>Put your do to list</p>
  </div>

  <div class="toDo">
    <ul id="list">

    </ul>

  </div>


  <input type="text" id="userInputAdd" placeholder="add">
  <button id="add">Add</button>
  <input type="text" id="userInputRemove" placeholder="remove">
  <button id="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Comment: *`$removeINput = $('#userInputRemove').val()` should be `$removeINput = $('#remove').val()`* shouldn't that be the other way round